# Find Cell's Column Given String

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to find the column of a cell which contains the string "Status".  The cell is in a different sheet named "Report" and I do not know where the cell is; I only know exactly what it contains. All I need to know is the column that the cell is in. How would I go about doing this (in VBA)? Any help would be greatly appreciated!  My code so far is below:

```
Sheets("Report").Select
Dim header_cell As Variant
Set header_cell = Cells.Find(what:="Status")
```

Comment: Is *Status* in the top row? Is it guaranteed to be there?

Comment: Yes, "Status" is in the top row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you avoid activating the worksheet in order to use it.

```
    Dim header_cell As Range
    With Sheets("Report")
        'this searches just row 1
        'Set header_cell = .Rows(1).Find(what:="Status", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
        'this searches the whole worksheet
        Set header_cell = .Cells.Find(what:="Status", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
        Debug.Print header_cell; "Column: " & header_cell.Column
        Debug.Print header_cell; "Address: " & header_cell.Address(0, 0, ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, external:=True)
    End With
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more on methods to get away from relying on select and activate.

Answer (score 2):

As well,

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, lookRng As Range, c As Range
    Set sh = Sheets("Report")
    Set lookRng = sh.Range("A1:Z1")

    Set c = lookRng.Find(what:="Status", lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox c.Address
    Else: MsgBox "Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new variable, say "`dim header_cell_column as Integer`"; you can do

```
header_cell_column = Cells.Find(what:="Status").Column
```

Comment: also `header_cell_column = application.match("status", sheets("Report").rows(1), 0)`